# Quotient of Pareto and Gamma random variables

Tags: random-variable, gamma-distribution, pareto-distribution

I cannot find an explicit formula for the quotient of a Pareto random variable divided by a Gamma random variable.

The only that I found is something like, for $P(X)$ pareto's like and $P(Y)$ Gamma's like distribution, is for $Z = \frac{X}{X + Y}$.

Is there any derivation to get $P(\frac{X}{Y})$, knowing $P(Z)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "knowing P(Z)"?

Comment: I mean the PDF of Z, P_Z(Z), with Z defined above.